# Take an SSH stream as a perl script input rather than a physical file

Tags: bash, perl, ssh

Is there a way in Linux taking a terminal/SSH stream as an input to another program.

I can get the following to work without issue:

```
#!/bin/bash
FIFO="$1"
ps auwx | grep "[m]rLogger 192.168.10.10"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    exit
fi
while [ 1 ]
do
  /usr/bin/sshpass -p MrLoggertemp /usr/bin/ssh -t -t -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l mrlogger 192.168.10.10 >> "$FIFO"
  echo "sshpass failed. restarting"
  sleep 1
done
```

.. and it will stream to a file

But I want to stream this to a perl script that I want to do some processing and then load into a dataset.

Is there a way to do the following in the perl script like:

```
my $fifo_fh;
my $fifo_file = <The output of the stream above>
open($fifo_fh, "+< $fifo_file") or die
```

Thanks..

Comment: Replace `>> ...` with `| perl ...` the just read from STDIN

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure exactly what your command "stream"s or what exactly you need with it.

But yes a Perl script can act as a filter, in a number of ways.

If you want to pipe a stream into the scirpt then read it from `STDIN` (perl's handle for fd 0)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

while (my $line_in = <STDIN>) { 
    chomp $line_in;   # remove newline
    # ...             # process
    say $line_in;     # prints for demo
}
```

Now with the command

```
ls -l . | script.pl
```

the lines of output from `ls -l .` are processed in the `script.pl` (only printed above).

So with your example instead of `cmd >> "$FIFO"` have `cmd | script.pl` and in the script write (append) to the file, after suitable processing.

If you'd rather do all this from inside a script, a basic way is to use a "[pipe-open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Opening-a-filehandle-into-a-command)"

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @cmd = qw(ls -l .);

open(my $in, '-|', @cmd) or die "Can't pipe-open @cmd: $!";

while (my $line_in = <$in>) { 
    chomp $line_in;
    # ...
    say $line_in;
}
```

With the command passed as a list (`@cmd`) it is assumed that  the first element of `@cmd` is the program to run, which is directly invoked and the rest of `@cmd` is passed to it as its arguments. This way a shell is altogether avoided, even if there are shell metacharacters in the command.

But if the command is meant to use a shell then write it as a string, or pass it as `"@cmd"`, where quoting interpolates `@cmd` into a string with spaces between elements.  See linked docs.

Then, there are libraries that facilitate and improve this. I'd first recommend [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run); it is the most complex one but also by far the most powerful, allowing your program to run a mini-shell almost.<sup>†</sup>

Let me know how this meshes (or not) with your uses so that we can adjust it, if needed.

---

When a loop condition is written as `while (<$fh>)` then a line that it reads, via `<>` operator from a filehandle `$fh`, gets assigned to an omnipresent default, [`$_` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$ARG). (If we explicitly assign to a variable, like I do above for clarity, then the deal is off and `$_` is undefined.)

That variable, `$_`, is a default for many other operators, including `chomp` and `say`.

Then examples above can be written as

```
while (<$in>) { 
    chomp;
    ...      # process $_, which has the line of input
    say;
}
```

This can lead to very lean and readable code, if used correctly.  But if we end up needing a lot of explicit uses of `$_` in the loop body (not everything takes it by default!), or end up with cryptic code, then please by all means introduce and use a nice lexical variable.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Basic uses are simple.

Comment: I tried your Perl script from above, and it work.  I am going to play with it over the next few days and see if that solves it.

Comment: @PhoneHarold Alright, let me know if questions come up

Comment: @PhoneHarold Great :)  Let me know if there are follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

Another skeleton approach use Linux names pipes. 
It is real time communication via remote server.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

```bash
mkfifo streamFile    # make pipe file.
exec 3<> streamFile  # change descriptor to not block r/w

# /* Here is if any line appears on streamFile it will pipe to Perl.
#    Whatever content appears on remote /var/log/messages pass to $line

cat streamFile - | ssh user@server  'tail -f /var/log/messages' |  while read line ; do 
    echo $line | perl;   # /* of course it fail, becasue perl expect differnt syntax. \
                         # /* You can change another file which tail file for perl lang
done
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do that!

Comment: If you want to use Linux utilities then this is one of the best practice. Named pipes is very common. Otherwise  you have develop your own socketing to get streaming. Instead of named pipes, you can use files from disk, but not prefereable